# Rails: How to use a before_filter to protect multiple methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, before-filter

So, I have this code in a controller:

```
before_filter :require_login, :only => :new, :edit, :destroy
```

My controller has these methods: **index, new, edit, create, update, show, destroy.**
What I want to do is to protect with login_required (:require_login in the code) the methods: **new, edit, destroy,** but the above code doesn't work, I can protect one method if i have, for example:

```
before_filter :require_login, :only => :new
```

But I want to protect the three of them, How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing square brackets around the `only` option's value:

```
 before_filter :require_login, :only => [:new, :edit, :destroy]
```

It's not working because the Ruby interpreter doesn't know where the options for only start and the arguments for `before_filter` continue. This is case where you need to be explicit about the container.

Comment: Thanks just discovered that before reading your answer, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array:

```
before_filter :require_login, :only => [:new, :edit, :destroy]
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh I was a FOOL!!! it was just matter of putting them in array form -.- like this:

```
before_filter :require_login, :only => [:new, :edit, :destroy]
```

Sorry for the obvious question.